# Using F# to search for an element and then adding sibling node

Tags: f#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Am trying to use F#, for one of the utility jobs that I need to run.

From a directory containing xml config files, I want to identify all the files that contain a particular node with an attribute being looked up and on finding a match, I would like to insert an sibling node in the same file.
I have written the snippet to identify all the files and now I have a sequence of files which I want to iterate and search for the attribute and append if necessary.

```
open System.Xml.Linq

let byElementName elementToSearch = XName.Get(elementToSearch)

let xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\Some.xml")
xmlDoc.Descendants <| byElementName "Elem"
|> Seq.collect(fun(riskElem) -> riskElem.Attributes <| byElementName "type" )
|> Seq.filter(fun(pvAttrib) -> pvAttrib.Value = "abc")
|> Seq.map(fun(pvAttrib) -> pvAttrib.Parent)
|> Seq.iter(printfn "%A")
```

**What I want to do is instead of the last printf, add another node of the type `"Elem"` with the `type = "abc2"`**

```xml
    <Product name="Node" inheritsfrom="Base">
      <SupportedElems>
        <Elem type="abc" methodology="abcmeth" />
        <Elem type="def" methodology="defmeth" />
</SupportedElems>
</Product>
```

Result XML:

```xml
<Product name="Node" inheritsfrom="Base">
  <SupportedElems>
    <Elem type="abc" methodology="abcmeth" />
    <Elem type="abc2" methodology="abcmeth" /> <!-- NEW ROW TO BE ADDED HERE -->
    <Elem type="def" methodology="defmeth" />
```

Comment: Did you forget some closing tags? The xml file is not well-formed.

Comment: the xml continues further with similar tags.. will edit the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion complex LINQ to XML queries are clumsy, and better done with XPath:

```
open System.Xml.Linq
open System.Xml.XPath

xmlDoc.XPathEvaluate("//Elem[@type='abc']") :?> _
|> Seq.cast<XElement>
|> Seq.iter (fun el -> 
  el.AddAfterSelf(XElement.Parse(@"<Elem type=""abc2"" methodology=""abcmeth""/>")))
```

XML document afterward:

```xml
<Product name="Node" inheritsfrom="Base">
  <SupportedElems>
    <Elem type="abc" methodology="abcmeth" />
    <Elem type="abc2" methodology="abcmeth" />
    <Elem type="def" methodology="defmeth" />
  </SupportedElems>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function correctly finds the `Elem` elements from the file, but it does not print anything. The `elem.Value` property that you're printing refers to the *body* of the element, which is empty in your case. If you use the following input then it prints "one" and "two":

```
<Product name="Node" inheritsfrom="Base"> 
  <SupportedElems> 
    <Elem type="abc" methodology="abcmeth">one</Elem>
    <Elem type="def" methodology="defmeth">two</Elem>
  </SupportedElems> 
</Product>
```

You can print the entire element (instead of just the body) like this:

```
let pvElement (configFile : string) =  
  let xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse configFile 
  xmlDoc.Descendants(byElementName "Elem")
  |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

If you want to pick a specific element (with some specified attribute) and then do something if the element was found, you can probably use the `Seq.tryPick` function, but that would be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Tomas! Srry, the question was not clear in the first instance. The printfn is just for debugging. I have updated it further. Hopefully, its clearer now.

Comment: @Codex - I thought you have troubles with finding the right element. Regarding adding - what have you tried so far? Did you find the `Add` method of `XElement` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add.aspx)? What XML do you want to get as a result?

Comment: I have updated the result XML. For adding the node, I am trying to use the AddAfterSelf method, but that doesnt seem to help. No compile errors either. "let InsertElement (elementToInsertAfter:XElement) = do elementToInsert |> elementToInsertAfter.AddAfterSelf"